# PHP New Line : \n Not Working

Tags: php

Let's say I have this variable :

```
$Include = "Line 1;
            //some Line 2 here";
```

and I want to write that variable into file and get exactly 2 lines like this :

```
Line1;
//some Line 2 here
```

but when I try to do it by using this code :

```
$Filename = 'somefile.php';
$Handle = fopen($Filename, "r");
$Contents = fread($Handle, filesize($Filename));
fclose($Handle);

$Contents = str_replace ('replace this', $Include, $Contents);
```

I see only one line like this :

```
Line 1; //some Line 2 here
```

how to make 2 lines using 1 variable? thanks

Comment: `$Include = "Line 1;\n//some Line 2 here";`?

Comment: Are you sure that somefile.php is being written to properly?  What does it look like when you open it with another file viewing program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Include = "Line 1; \r\n" .
           "        //some Line 2 here";
```

Comment: Well it's highly likely that the `\n` is already there and only the `\r` missing. Take care. But maybe this is an old MAC and the `\n` is missing? Who knows, better not educate the OP.

Comment: @Nikolaos : it works bro!! thanks for you \r\n... I must wait for 3 minutes to accept your answer...

Comment: @RobertHanson I am glad you got it resolved.

Comment: @RobertHanson: Take care, you now might have the following byte-sequence: `\r\n\n` which technically is not what you're looking for and might introduce problems later on. I edited the answer so it becomes more clear.

Answer (score 5):

If you are displaying the content using `echo` as an html content, you need to use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function.

```
echo nl2br($file_content);
```

This function will transform all \n into `<br />` html tags which will be displayed on an html page as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the `\n` to your string to see a linebreak. I don't see any in your example above.
`$Include = "Line 1;\n//some Line 2 here";`

Comment: I did. by using /n and it doesn't work, that's why I removed it.

Comment: You have to make sure you put it in double quotes and not single quotes.